# Dynamic Role from database to show content to user based on their role

Tags: java, spring, security, acl

How can i have dynamic role from database for a user in 
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
or 
?

I want ROLE_ADMIN to be dynamic instead of static or hard code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to store the different ROLES in a Properties file and get them in the code, like:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(" + PropertyManager.getProperty("role.admin") + "')" + '"')
```

Or when you configure the GRANT permissions to the different users you are possibility to select different columns for each role. So in the Controller of the app redirect to the specific method

Comment: I have roles and their permission stored in database, and admin can allow or disallow role and permission to users. So i want role dynamically from database. how can i do that?

Comment: Three ways: 1.- Get the permission from a Table of the DB. 2.- Get the permissions from a Properties file. 3.- Put "hardcoded" into the code.

Comment: how get from DB in @PreAuthorize?